# Sentence Help: Adding め After the Word for Owl

Tags: nouns

I am reading Harry Potter in Japanese, and there is a line that reads:「 あのふくろうめを黙らせられないなら、始末してしまえ！」

The way I interpreted this quote is as, "if that owl cannot be made silent, then make it end!" However, I can't figure out why there is a め after the word for owl, ふくろう.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, he's saying "If that d****d owl doesn't shut up..." and something about plucking the life out the poor bird.

Comment: Why are you quoting yourself?